# Route group with optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm wondering if it is possible to use optional parameters in a group prefix.

Using it with `{parameter?}` like in any other route doesn't work:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'foo/{foo_id?}'), function() {
   Route::any('bar', 'ApiFooController@bar');
});
```

I would like to catch both `foo/bar` and `foo/2/bar`.

As much as I can see, it only works without the questionmark but then `foo/bar`(without the parameter) throws an error.

I would like to avoid defining two seperate groups which would be a workaround. Maybe Important to note: `bar` is a custom function in addition to a resource so I'm not trying to define a resource (like `foo.bar`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have to define the route twice, but you don't have to create another group.

Does this work for you?

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'foo'),function() {
        Route::any('bar', 'ApiFooController@bar');
        Route::any('{foo_id}/bar', 'ApiFooController@bar');
    });
```

Comment: Hmm yes there are two solutions so far. If I don't have a lot of routes it might be better to define the route twice. If I have a lot of routes, maybe defining the group twice is better. I would of course still prefere to define an optional parameter in the group as it is possible in routes. Looks like laravel is lacking that feature.